# Storybook is loading stories from a yarn/lerna monorepo's packages' node_modules folder

Tags: yarnpkg, storybook, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I'm using storybook in a lerna/yarn workspaces monorepo. I noticed today that storybook is trying to load stories from `packages/**/node_modules/@scope/foo/stories/foo.stories.js` I've tried logging out the require.context keys in config.js but its not logged to console. Is there a ready way to tell storybook not to load symlinked local `node_modules`? Is it likely I've misconfigured storybook? Here's my config:

```js
import '@storybook/addon-console';
import { withA11y } from '@storybook/addon-a11y';
import { addDecorator, addParameters, configure } from '@storybook/polymer';

import theme from './my-theme'

const req = require.context('../packages', true, /\.stories\.js$/);
const load = filename =>  req(filename);

addParameters({ options: {
  panelPosition: 'right',
  theme,
} })

addDecorator(withA11y)

configure(function loadStories() {
  req.keys()
    .filter(filename => !filename.match(/packages\/.*\/node_modules/))
    .forEach(load);
}, module);
```

example error:

```
ERROR in ./packages/input/node_modules/@scope/collapse/stories/collapse.stories.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../button/src/my-button' in '/Users/bennyp/Documents/web-components/packages/input/node_modules/@scope/collapse/stories'
```

This causes the storybook build to break.

How do I tell storybook not to load stories from internal `node_modules`?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex solved the problem

```js
const req = require.context('../packages', true,
  /^((?![\\/]node_modules[\\/]).)*\.stories\.js$/
);
```